architecture for a cluster of 3 web servers with proxmox VE
Good morning,
I have to propose an architecture for a cluster of 3 web servers for a company with proxmox VE.
I plan to install 2 debian 12 VMs on each server (one for the site and the other for the MySQL database).
1- Regarding backup and security, what do you recommend?
2- Which server (brand and model) do you recommend?
I haven't done anything yet.
Thanks in advance.
